# Connect a particular MySQL Database according to an html form

Tags: php, html, mysql

What i want to do is to connect to a particular Database according to the value of an html form, first of all is it possible ?

I have got some code to propose :

This is my form in the previous page :

```
<form method="post" action="connexion.php">
                  <li> <strong><b>Aircraft</b></strong> : <input type="text" name="Aircraft" placeholder="MRJ" /><br /> </li>
                  <li> <strong><b>Systeme</b></strong> : <input type="text" name="Systeme" placeholder="ATAXX" /><br /> </li>
                  <li> <strong><b>Projet</b></strong> :  <input type="text" name="Projet" placeholder="CMA" /><br /> </li>
                  <br />
                 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

And my code for the connexion.php :

```
 <?php
/* Database credentials. Assuming you are running MySQL
server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */
define('DB_SERVER', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'root');
define('DB_PASSWORD', '@Rugby3390');
define('DB_NAME', 'ata."$Systeme"');

/* Attempt to connect to MySQL database */
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

// Check connection
if($mysqli === false){
    die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . $mysqli->connect_error);
}
header("location: ../FailureCondition/failurecondition$_POST[Systeme].php");
?>
```

So if you could understand me, according to data entered in Systeme, i would like to connect to a special database named ata(user input) and redirect to a page whit also the information of the user input named failurecondition(user).php

What s wrong in my code ?

Thx

Comment: try this `define('DB_NAME', 'ata'.$_POST['Systeme']);`

Comment: you did not close form tag, and define('DB_NAME', 'ata'.$Systeme);  AND header("location: ../FailureCondition/failurecondition/".$_POST[Systeme].".php");

Comment: What is `$Systeme` in `define('DB_NAME', 'ata."$Systeme"');`.?

Comment: $Systeme is the name of the variable from my FORM from the previous page

Comment: variables are not preserved between postbacks. You need to read the form field from the POST variables for the most recent postbacks. e.g. `$_POST['Systeme']`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Nirav and Arkits' solution should solve the problem, it strikes me as fundamentally wrong to define a constant from a variable. I suggest that this is more correct:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD,$_POST['Systeme']);
```

Further, as is the case here, where your application has multiple databases, using an implicit database in queries is likely to cause pain later. If the seperation of databases is merely an organizational concern, then a better approach would be to explicitly reference the database in the queries:

```
$activeDB=$_POST['Systeme'];
$sql="SELECT * FROM ${activeDB}.atable";
```

OTOH if it is intended as a means of providing scalability, then your code does not address this - and you should be using something like:

```
$dbs=array(
   'db1'=>array(
       'user'=>'mysqluser', 'host'=>'localhost', 'password'=>'s3cr3t'
   ),
   'db2'=>array(
       'user'=>'mysqluser', 'host'=>'localhost', 'password'=>'s3cr3t'
   ),
   'db3'=>array(
       'user'=>'other', 'host'=>'192.168.22.4', 'password'=>'swordfish'
   )
   ...
);
$use=$dbs[$_POST['Systeme']];
if (!is_array($use)) {
    ...
}
$mysqli = new mysqli($use['host'], $use['user'], $use['password'], $_POST['Systeme']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Close the form tag (`</form>`) in your html page if not already. And try this:

```
define('DB_NAME', 'ata'.$_POST['Systeme']);
```